# Error when i insert multiple products in listview in c# sql. What is wrong?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a listview which is adding some products in the database. If i insert one product, it works perfectly. The problem with this code is the cmd2.Parameters.Clear(); If i insert more than one product in the form listview, it only sends the last one to the database. How can i do to insert all products, because it seems that if i don't use parameters.clear, it's not working at all. There is no error thrown, it just does not insert products.

This is the code:

```
private void InsertOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
        //---------------Inserare client--------------------
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertClients", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (TextBoxClientNou.Enabled)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeClient", TextBoxClientNou.Text);
        }

        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeClient", ClientExistent.Text);
        }

        var IDClientParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDClient", SqlDbType.Int);
        IDClientParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var IDClient = (int)IDClientParameter.Value;
        con.Close();


        //--------------------Inserare Produse------------------

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("InsertProducts", con);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        

        foreach (ListViewItem item in ListaProduse.Items)
        {
            cmd2.Parameters.Clear(); //Problem here
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Denumire", item.Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantitate", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dimensiuni", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comentarii", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            
        }

        var IDProductParameter = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@IDProdus", SqlDbType.Int);
        IDProductParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        con.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var IDProdus = (int)IDProductParameter.Value;
        con.Close();


        //--------------------Inserare comanda-------------------

        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("InsertOrders", con);
        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDClient", IDClient);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDProdus", IDProdus);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataInceput", dateTimePicker1.Text);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataSfarsit", dateTimePicker2.Text);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Facturata", factstatus);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Livrata", livstatus);

        con.Open();
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). It is also difficult to believe that all your parameters (and associated columns) are nvarchar(50). Names like "size" or "quantity" smell like numeric values

Answer (score 0):

you have to execute the query inside your loop, cause you're adding parameters in the loop (if two ListViewItem so 8 parameters), that's why you're getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the parameters without clearing the originals. You can either use `Parameters.Clear()` or you can change the `Value` of existing parameters. You then need to execute the command *within* the loop.

> Note that you *must* use `using` blocks to dispose the connection. And if you do so, the connection will be closed automatically

> Specify the parameter types and lengths explicitly

```cs
var listIds = new List<int>();

using (var con = new SqlConnection(YourConnString))
using (var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("InsertProducts", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
using (var cmd3 = new SqlCommand("InsertOrders", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
{
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@DenProd", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ProdQuant", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ProdSize", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ProdComm", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    var IDProductParameter = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ProdID", SqlDbType.Int);
    IDProductParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    cmd3.Parameters.Add("@IDClient", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IDClient;
    cmd3.Parameters.Add("@IDProdus", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd3.Parameters.Add("@DataInceput", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
    cmd3.Parameters.Add("@DataSfarsit", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker2.Text;
    cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Facturata", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = factstatus;
    cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Livrata", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = livstatus;

    con.Open();

    foreach (ListViewItem item in ListaProduse.Items)
    {
        cmd2.Parameters["@DenProd"].Value = item.Text;
        cmd2.Parameters["@ProdQuant"].Value = item.SubItems[1].Text;
        cmd2.Parameters["@ProdSize"].Value = item.SubItems[1].Text;
        cmd2.Parameters["@ProdComm"].Value = item.SubItems[1].Text;
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var IDProdus = (int)IDProductParameter.Value; // do something with this value

        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDProdus", IDProdus);
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I must say, ideally you should use either a Table Valued parameter or `SqlBulkCopy` to do this in bulk, it will not be performant for large numbers of rows.

Comment: That var IDProdus is accessed from outside of the foreach, and if i put it inside it says "It does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You need to think how you are going to deal with multiple `IDProdus` results. Perhaps you should put them in a list. That's why I added the comment `// do something with this value`

Comment: The IDProdus in var IDProdus = (int)IDProductParameter.Value; i must access from outside the foreach and i have no idea how to do that.
It is here: cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDProdus", IDProdus);

Comment: This is inside the foreach loop: var IDProdus = (int)IDProductParameter.Value;
I need to access it from here: cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDProdus", IDProdus); - which is outside
The foreach loop inserts the products from the listview rows in the database. I need to access this var so i can insert the product id in the Orders table column.

Comment: Again: **what do you want to *do* with it?** You're not telling me, you're just saying "I need to access this". You will have multiple results, one for each run of the loop. What would you like to do with each result? Put it in a list, what?

Comment: I updated the code in the post. Might as well put it in a list. The basic idea is that i want to insert the listview rows in the database table. One product inserts ok, two or more products throws error.

Comment: OK you can use something like `listIds.Add(IDProdus);` have modified the answer. Or perhaps you need to execute this `cmd3` inside the loop also, it's unclear how it relates to the first command.

Comment: Ok, so now it inserts the products ok, but i get this error: System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] to a known managed provider native type.' on cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery(); in orders insert

Comment: Yeah you can't insert a list like that. I suggest you create a *new* question clearly explaining how this new `cmd3` relates to the first one, showing your table schema (relationships) etc

Comment: You can find the cmd3 code on my edited post today above your edited code.

Comment: I've modified it further but really guessing in the dark here without knowing what the relationship between the different tables and procedures is.

Comment: I managed to make it work with the   cmd2.Parameters.Clear();  in the foreach, but now it only inserts the last row from the listview

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in ListaProduse.Items)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("InsertProducts", con);
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DenProd", item.Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdQuant", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdSize", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdComm", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            var IDProductParameter = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ProdID", SqlDbType.Int);
            IDProductParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            con.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            var IDProdus = (int)IDProductParameter.Value;
            con.Close();
        }
```